# Grab values from dynamic form content angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-forms

I am working with a back-end API that I query for flight data, which I then loop over and display the data. My template code looks like this...

```
<form novalidate #form="ngForm">
    <div class="flight-table">
      <header fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
        <div fxFlex="25">Flights</div>
          <div fxFlex="17">Class</div>
          <div fxFlex="18">Price (AED)</div>
          <div fxFlex="15">PAX</div>
        <div fxFlex="25">Total</div>
      </header>

      <main>
        <div class="flights-body--row" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between" *ngFor="let flight of data.flights; let i = index">
          <p fxFlex="25">{{flight['flightName']}}</p>
          <p fxFlex="17">{{flight['flightClass']}}</p>
          <p fxFlex="18">{{flight['flightPrice'] | number}}</p>
          <p fxFlex="15" fxLayout="column">
            <mat-select placeholder="Ticket(s)">
              <mat-option *ngFor="let pax of counter" [value]="pax">{{ pax }} </mat-option>
              </mat-select>
           </p>
           <p fxFlex="25">AED 0</p>
         </div>

         <div class="flights-body--row" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
           <p class="capitalize" fxFlex="75"><strong>Total transport</strong></p>
           <p class="center-text" fxFlex="25"><strong>AED 0</strong></p>
         </div>
      </main>
    </div>
</form>
```

[image: Flights table]

When a user selects a number of tickets from the PAX dropdown, I'd like to update both the `row total` and the `total transport`. I'd need to be able to grab the value of the `PAX select box` and multiply it by `flight['flightPrice']` but I can't quite figure out how to, because I can't know how many items are in the flights array. What you see is just one row but there could be more.

Also, I'd like to capture the value for each row. I've thought about adding a hidden form field for each row or sth like that. I'm not quite sure how to deal with this.
Is there some better way?

**Update**

I'm struggling with how to capture the selected rows. I've tried adding a hidden input field in each row like so..

```
<input 
  matInput 
  [name]="flight['flightName']-flight['flightClass']-pax-flight['flightPrice']" 
  [value]="total"
  ngModel>
```

That doesn't seem to work. The goal is to have each selected row stored in an object like so...
The dashes separate the `flightName`, `flightClass`, `pax` and `flightPrice` with the value being the `total (pax * flightPrice)` and pax the number of passengers.

```
flights: {
  lufthansa-business-2-60: 120,
  flyEmirates-first-3-50: 150
}
```

How should I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you create a dedicated component for your basket items. 
You then have an isolated scope you can work with and i.e. use `[(ngModel)]` to set the selected number of pax on your component (for which you have to import the `FormsModule` in your app/feature module).
You can then reuse that value to compute the total price for a flight.

To get the total for the entire transport (sum over all basket items), you'd also need to pass data between components. A `BasketService` that keeps track of your basket items can help with that.  I created a little stackblitz to demonstrate how to do this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tpenou

The relevant parts are:

```
export class BasketItemComponent implements OnDestroy {

  @Input() flight: Flight;
  paxOptions = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
  pax = 0;

  constructor(private  basketService: BasketService) {
    this.basketService.registerBasketItemComponent(this);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.basketService.removeBasketItemComponent(this);
  }

  get total() {
    return this.flight.flightPrice * this.pax;
  }

}
```

And the template:

```
<div class="flights-body--row" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between" >
    <p fxFlex="25">{{flight['flightName']}}</p>
    <p fxFlex="17">{{flight['flightClass']}}</p>
    <p fxFlex="18">{{flight['flightPrice'] | number}}</p>
    <p fxFlex="15" fxLayout="column">
      <mat-select placeholder="Ticket(s)" [(ngModel)]="pax">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let pax of paxOptions" [value]="pax">{{ pax }} </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
     </p>
     <p fxFlex="25">AED {{ total }}</p>
</div>
```

And the `BasketService`:

```
export class BasketService {

  basketItems: BasketItemComponent[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  get total() {
    return this.basketItems.reduce( (a, b) => a + b.total, 0);
  }

  registerBasketItemComponent(c: BasketItemComponent) {
    this.basketItems.push(c);
  }

  removeBasketItemComponent(c: BasketItemComponent) {
    this.basketItems.splice(this.basketItems.indexOf(c), 1);
  }
}
```

You would also have to alter your for loop to make use of your newly created custom component:

```
<form novalidate #form="ngForm">
  <div class="flight-table">
    <header fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
      <div fxFlex="25">Flights</div>
        <div fxFlex="17">Class</div>
        <div fxFlex="18">Price (AED)</div>
        <div fxFlex="15">PAX</div>
      <div fxFlex="25">Total</div>
    </header>

    <main>
      <app-basket-item [flight]="flight" *ngFor="let flight of data.flights; let i = index">

      </app-basket-item>

       <div class="flights-body--row" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
         <p class="capitalize" fxFlex="75"><strong>Total transport</strong></p>
         <p class="center-text" fxFlex="25"><strong>AED {{transportTotal}}</strong></p>
       </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Dude thank you so much for your answer. The solution seems much more involved than I had hoped it would be though. Could it be any shorter?

Comment: @NelsonKing Of course you can do it in a shorter fashion, but it's not necessarily ideal from a maintainability perspective. Created an alternative version on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yz1hqc

Comment: I hear you. Thank you so much.

Comment: @NelsonKing What do you mean by selected? rows that have a number of pax assigned?

Comment: @NelsonKing I adapted the latter stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yz1hqc) with a change listener on the pax element that populates a `selectedFlights` object on `AppComponent` when the number of pax changes. Have a look and let me know if you have any questions. (Note the `console.log` of `this.selectedFlights` which prints the object in the structure you desire)

Comment: The line `this.data.flights.reduce((total, f) => f['flightPrice'] * (f['pax'] || 0) + total, 0);` in the `transportTotal` function gives me the error `Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'Object'. ts(2365)`. The API returns the value of `flightPrice` as a string but even when I `parseInt` on both `flightPrice` and pax I still get that error. I'm stuck and I didn't want to ask a new question because herein lies the entire context.

Comment: @NelsonKing Maybe typescript is ranting because the `reduce` is actually a combination of map and reduce and the type inference has issues with that. Does it work if you write it like this: `this.data.flights.map(f => Number.parseFloat(f['flightPrice']) * (f['pax'] || 0)).reduce((total, flightPrice) => total + flightPrice, 0);` ? If that's not the issue please fork my stackblitz and mock the data as it is returned from your API so I have somewhere to start from

Comment: Oh, that worked like a charm. You're a life saver! Many thanks.